# Epoch is too precise

Tags: javascript, node.js, epoch

When writing to a database I add a timestamp. But it is a bit too precise; I just want to have Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute. Now I get the epoch down to the millisecond.

What should below be to only generate as mentioned above?

```
"TimeStamp": String(Date.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round to the nearest minute by dividing by the number of milliseconds in a minute and multiplying that again by that factor after having rounded (or truncated) it:

```
Math.round(Date.now() / 60000) * 60000
```

Use `Math.floor` if you need to truncate to the minute instead of rounding to the nearest one.